# Jetpack compose recipes simple app problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm new to jetpack compose and used to work with XML for various tasks. I'm attempting to build a basic recipes app in jetpack compose, but every time I run the app, I get a blank black screen. I carefully reviewed my code, but couldn't identify the issue, as I'm still getting acquainted with jetpack compose. I'm sharing my code with you for correction. Thanks in advance.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RecipeApp()
        }
    }
}


val recipes = listOf(
    Recipe("Spaghetti", R.drawable.spaghetti, "Boil noodles..."),
    Recipe("Pizza", R.drawable.pizza, "Knead the dough..."),
    Recipe("Sushi", R.drawable.sushi, "Spread rice on seaweed...")
)
fun navigate(navController: NavController, recipe: Recipe) {
    navController.navigate("recipe_detail/${recipe.name}/${recipe.iconRes}")
}

@Composable
fun RecipeListItem(recipe: Recipe, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = onClick)) {
        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = recipe.iconRes), contentDescription = null)
        Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Text(text = recipe.name)
    }
}

@Composable
fun RecipeDetailScreen(recipe: Recipe) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = recipe.iconRes), contentDescription = null)
        Text(text = recipe.name, fontSize = 24.sp)
        Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Text(text = recipe.instructions)
    }
}

@Composable
fun RecipeApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "recipe_list") {
        composable("recipe_list") {
            RecipeListScreen(navController, recipes)
        }

        composable("recipe_detail/{name}/{icon}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("name") { type = NavType.StringType },
                navArgument("icon") { type = NavType.IntType }
            )) { backStackEntry ->
            val name = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("name")
            val icon = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("icon")
            name?.let {
                RecipeDetailScreen(recipes.first { it.name == name })
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RecipeListScreen(navController: NavController, recipes: List<Recipe>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(recipes) { recipe ->
            RecipeListItem(recipe = recipe) {
                navigate(navController, recipe)
            }
        }
    }
}

data class Recipe(val name: String,
                  val iconRes: Int,
                  val instructions: String)
```

I tried to log the errors but I did not find anything special.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

A Jetpack Compose Application usually has a [`Surface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Surface(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0)) as a base Composable. All further Composables and the NavHost will be drawn onto that Surface.

A typical Activity structure looks like this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            RecipeAppTheme {  // referencing theme in Theme.kt file
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    RecipeApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend that you create a [new Compose project in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#create-new) using the *Empty Activity* template. This will create this boilerplate code for you and will also generate a Theme.kt file where you can customize the colors of your App.

Comment: I did as you said and even though when I  click somewhere in the screen I open one of the list items but the main screen is still black.

Comment: I did as you said and even though when I  click somewhere in the screen I open one of the list items but the main screen is still black. I don't know how to attach images in a comment so I did them as an answer to my post under your answer. Please see them if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77826662/23253218

Comment: Please try to create a new Compose Project in Android Studio and report back if the error persists also in a new project.
I editws your post and included the pictures there, you now can delete your answer below with the two pictures.